# Expo React Native Simulator Bundles But Crashes on Open (New Macbook M1 max)

Tags: react-native, expo, ios-simulator, apple-m1

I recently got a new Macbook Pro M1 Max and am trying to set up my expo react native environment (VScode). The app bundles and everything is working as it should, but when I try to open the Expo Go app in the simulator, the app crashes (shown below).
Everything works fine when I open the Expo app from my iPhone, so I think it is just a simulator issue. Does anyone[image: video of the app crashing in simulator] know what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an error with the app for the emulator, I don't know the exact reason but the app work with rosetta installed. I think is because the app was made for intel chips.

With this command the app works!

`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Comment: Thanks mate that worked for me, I've Apple M1 and Ventura 13.3.1